# How do I add images plus caption and credits to a expressionengine blog posting

Tags: image, expressionengine

A blog posting (single entry page) consists of text and images.
The channel “blog” has the field group “blog_entries”. The interesting fields in the fieldgroup are "blog_body" and the three relationship fields called "image1", "image2", "image3"
The images are stored in a different channel called "images". The fieldgroup "image_entries" has a few fields. The image upload field itself, the caption, credits and a few more.

I can combine images and text via the relationship fields.

My problem is: The editor should place the image where it has to be in the content. And he should be able to choose the size of the image (should it span 4,8,or 12 columns) The example below has an image eight columns wide.

Adding an image would add the following code

```
<div class="eight columns picture">
    <div id="copyright" class="text-right">
      &copy; <a href="#">Photographer name</a>, <a href="#">Flickr</a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x525&text=[700x525]" />
   <div class="panel">
     <p>I am the caption. Nulla corned beefsunt ball tip.</p>
  </div>
```

What I want to achive is:
The editor types the text into the blog_entries field within the CP. This field is a textarea with custom HTML buttons.
After two paragraphs of writing he needs an image to ilustrate what he wrote.
He clicks on a custom HTML button,sees the related images, gets to choose the size of the image (should it span 4,8 or 12 columns) and with the next click EE integrates all the neccessary code into the entry.
So the editor has not to worry about the DIVs and all the code but can position an previously uploaded image where ever he wants in the article.

How can I achive that?
I´m not bound to do it this way. If there´s another way or a plugin to solve that problem,I´d like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty different approach but one that I've used for this sort of thing in the past is Matrix. You set up the blog_body as a matrix field which is intended to have a row added for each breakpoint in the article (a breakpoint being the insertion of an image, for example).  And so the matrix might include 3 columns - one for the image, one for the image width (radio between your three different span widths, for example) and one for "paragraph content".

The challenge here though is that you're using a relationship field for the images rather than having the images as part of the blog entry.  Since a relationship field is not, to the best of my knowledge, a fieldtype you can use within a matrix field, that makes it a lot tougher to take this approach.  But if you are keep a fixed number of relationship fields - as you suggested, image1, image2, image3, then the first column in the matrix could simply be a radio button for the editor to choose between image1, image2 and image3 to be inserted at this breakpoint.  Not a typical use of Matrix, but it would allow you to be relative object-oriented about the editor's control over the content.

Hope that idea helps or sparks new ones!

Comment: Thanks, I have no issues having the images as part of the entry. But since I´ve never worked with Matrix: On the categories page I need to show the thumbnailed image first and then an artcile excerpt. This was the reason behind the separation of images and text. Normally I like the granular approach, but since I don´t want to re-use the images in other articles it´s ok to treat images and text as one block.

Comment: So for three images I would have 3 times the three rows, that that you mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah under those circumstances, you could do away with the relationship and separate channel for the images and just make the images a field within the blog entry.  The simplest way to handle it in concert with the formatting you asked about above, would be to make the image field one column in the matrix.  The beauty of this approach and abandoning the relationship thing is that now you would have the ability, thanks to the matrix field, to scale up or down to the blog posts's needs.  You could have one blog post with 5 images and another with none - process for your client remains the same.

Comment: So your body field would actually be a matrix of multiple columns - image (file), image position (dropdown/radio), body (wysiwyg) and if needed, additional columns tied to the image, such as alt text, caption, etc. The client would really only need to create a new row in the matrix for each time an image is needed within the body with your styling applied to it. Your template would simply need a little conditional magic to determine if an image is present in the row, and if so, insert the needed formatting around it, followed by the content of the WYWIWYG field.

Comment: It's a fair bit of horsepower to throw at it, but it would succeed in walling your client off from the formatting code needed to present your content this way.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use that approach on content rich website, but I generally use default field types. Just a variant of what Jean proposed, the underlying logic stays the same.

1. Images and text of blogpost in same channel
2. Determine the min and max number of images you want per post (usually I go with 3)
3. Instead of just having one body field, one caption field, one image field, and 1 field for your image dimensions (I usually use P&T field), you duplicate the whole lot three times (if you went with 3 images max).
4. I generally only make the first text + image + image configs fields mandatory
5. Your clients can now "compose" their own page with one, two or three images, displayed in various ways, but will stay in the boundaries you have defined.

Hope it helps

Comment: ok, so the trick is having 3 textfields instead of just 1 {blog_body} field. I assune, that you work with conditionals in the template to get rid of code that belongs to empty fields. How do you structure the CP page: All 3 text fields first, then the image related stuff or do you start with a textfield, than an image field to mimick the rendered page?

Comment: Yeah, that's a way to handle it natively. I'm not crazy about creating fixed fields that may or may not be used though, which is why I've started using the Matrix approach instead - then it's technically one field that expands or contracts to each entry's usage - no "empty gaps" in the data tables.  Too often when you fix a set like that, the client will come up with exceptions that you have to accommodate, but if the field itself is flexible, you're in good shape for the long term.  A good suggestion from Jerome though.